# Why I can't use XDebug to debug this simple PHP script? Is it XDebug not installed on my system?

Tags: php, debugging, aptana, xdebug, aptana3

I am very new in PHP development and I am finding some difficulties trying to use **XDebug** to debug the following simple test PHP script:

I am using Aptana 3 editor as IDE (but I think that this is not relevant) and I have setted 2 breakpoint on the first and on the second echo so I have tried to debug (**right click on the previous php file ---> Debug as ---> PHP Script**). Now I would expect that the execution stops one time on the first breackpoint and 5 times on the second.

The problem is that when I try to debug it I obtain that it is executed  and I obtain the following output message:

> BEGIN Hello Aptana StudioHello Aptana StudioHello Aptana StudioHello
>   Aptana StudioHello Aptana Studio

The problem is that the script is not debugged but is totaly executed without stopping on breakpoint.

Into the Aptana PHP interpreter settings I have these settings:

```
Name: Php-int

Executable Path: /usr/bin/php5

PHP ini file: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

PHP Debugger: XDebug
```

It show **XDebug** as standard debug system but it seems can't work so I am asking if XDebug is really installed.

To check if it is installed I have execute and info.php file containing the **phpinfo();** function and in its output I can't see any reference to XDebug so I am thinking that maybe it is not installed on my system.

In the previous **phpinfo()** output I also find this record:

```
extension_dir   /usr/lib/php5/20090626
```

so I think (but maybe this assertion is wrong) that it contains all the PHP5 extention. If I enter in this directory I can't see any reference to XDebug.

I also try to modify the previous **info.php** file in this way:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
xdebug_get_code_coverage();
?>
```

The **xdebug_get_code_coverage()** should return an array if XDebug is installed. It return nothing so I think that XDebug is not installed.

So, the problem is that is it not installed or can I have some other kind of problem? (because in Aptana I can see XDebug as a possibile debugging option).

If it is not installed what is the correct procedure to install it?

**EDIT 1:** this is the output of **php -m** statment:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:~$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib
```

Tnx

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` or `php -m` to see if the xdebug extension is loaded

Comment: I have edited the original post including the output of the php -m statment. It seems that I have not installed XDebug. Can you confirm me it? What can I do to correctly install it?

Comment: It should show up under `[Zend Modules]` If that's not the case. You need to install it.